# Issue with ROS2 Control [Humble] and Gazebo Garden Plugin Loading

Tags: ros2, gazebo-plugin, ros2-control, gz-sim

I'm currently working on a project where I am trying to use ROS 2 Humble Control in conjunction with Gazebo Garden. However, I am encountering an issue where the plugins are not loading as expected.

I have followed the documentation and setup instructions, but it seems like there might be a compatibility issue or a configuration step I might have missed. Has anyone else faced a similar problem or successfully integrated ROS2 Control [Humble] with Gazebo Garden? If so, could you please share any insights or tips on resolving this issue?

[Gazebo garden installation](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu#binary-installation-on-ubuntu)

sudo apt-get install ros-humble-ros-gzgarden

param.yaml

```
controller_manager:     # node name
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100
    use_sim_time: true

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    effort_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointGroupEffortController
      
  
effort_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100
    use_sim_time: true
    joints:
      - JOINT1
```

ros2 control plugin:

```
<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
          <plugin>gz_ros2_control/GazeboSimSystem</plugin>
          <!-- <plugin>ign_ros2_control/IgnitionSystem</plugin> -->
        </hardware>

        <joint name="JOINT1">
          <command_interface name="effort">
            <param name="min">-15</param>
            <param name="max">15</param>
          </command_interface>
          <state_interface name="velocity"/>
          <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>

    <gazebo>
        <!-- Joint state publisher -->
        <plugin filename="gz_ros2_control-system" name="gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin">
        <!-- <plugin filename="ign_ros2_control-system" name="ign_ros2_control::IgnitionROS2ControlPlugin">   -->
          <parameters>$(find m4e_mani_control)/config/param.yaml.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
      </gazebo>
```

launch_file:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription, ExecuteProcess
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

import os
import xacro

def generate_launch_description():
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default=True)

    # package information
    package_description = 'description'
    urdf_file = 'ros2_control_gazebo.xacro'
    robot_description_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_description),'urdf', urdf_file)    

    doc = xacro.parse(open(robot_description_path))
    xacro.process_doc(doc)
    params = {'robot_description': doc.toxml()}

    # Robot state publisher
    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[params],
        emulate_tty=True,
        output = 'screen',
    )

    # Spawn Gazebo model
    spawn_sim_robot = Node(
        package='ros_gz_sim',
        executable='create',
        arguments=['-string', doc.toxml(),
                   '-name', 'manipulator',
                   '-allow_renaming', 'true'],
        output='screen',
        emulate_tty=True,
    )

    # Spawn Joint state broadcaster controller
    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster",
                   "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    effort_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["effort_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    # Start Gazebo 
    try: 
        gazebo_launch_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('ros_gz_sim'), 'launch', 'gz_sim.launch.py')
    except:
        gazebo_launch_file = ""

    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([gazebo_launch_file]),
        launch_arguments=[('gz_args', ['-r -v 1 empty.sdf'])],
    )
    
    ## Launch description
    return LaunchDescription([

        # Launch
        gazebo,

        RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action= spawn_sim_robot,
            on_exit=[joint_state_broadcaster_spawner]
            )
        ),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action= joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
                on_exit=[effort_controller_spawner]
            )
        ),

        # Nodes
        spawn_sim_robot,
        robot_state_publisher,

        # Launch Arguments
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value=use_sim_time,
            description='If true, use simulated clock'),

    ])
```

error:
[image]

Additionally, I would appreciate any guidance on debugging and troubleshooting this specific plugin loading problem in the context of ROS 2 Humble Control and Gazebo Garden.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The error is rather difficult to read - it is quite small and the red colour doesn't help. Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)... Thanks.

Comment: I'll make the necessary updates once I resume work on this task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if garden is compatible with humble. Acc. to gz_ros2_control [repo](https://github.com/ros-controls/gz_ros2_control), it is not. If so, the plugin might be named ign_ros2_control.

Have you installed ign_ros2_control?
Try the demos from the humble branch.

Comment: When I install ign_ros2_control using the command sudo apt install ros-humble-ign-ros2-control, it automatically installs Gazebo Fortress as well. My packages function smoothly with Gazebo Fortress, and I aim to replicate the same functionality in Gazebo Garden.

Comment: as I said, I'm not sure if it is compatible.

Comment: Is it feasible to employ the Gazebo Bridge to transmit commands, allowing the model to respond within the simulation environment?